# How to place all the css code from .vue files into one .css file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm starting VueJS, I started my code from the original [Vue Loader Example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader-example) and I tested running `npm run dev` or `npm run build` but a question emerge : Is there a way to place all the css from the components in one place (like styles.min.css).

I added bootstrap as dependencies in my package.json and but when I do a `npm run build` I can only find the build.js file in `dist`, that's all.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would you want to do that... Vue components, like react components have a way to put all content for a component in one place... if you want to create a single css file.. then just don't use components..

Comment: This doesn't make sense : Even if I use Vue.js component, there is a single build.js file generated. Why it wouldn't do the same for css ?

Comment: If you check the source for all css in effect for any element, then for the vue component it is just `<style></style>` and not any other file that you want generated. My point wasn't why it won't do it for you... If you want to have your css in a seperate file, then just create one... what's the problem? There are plenty of build tools for that too..

Comment: I believe we are not talking about the same thing. What I want is to merge all the `<style></style>` inlined in the html page, generated from the `*.vue` files, in one, external `.css` file. I'm also sure there is tools for that, hence my question :)

Comment: QUESTION: Why would you want to do that?  ANSWER: IE11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a plugin for that

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

and then configure it in your webpack.config.js

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  // other options...
  module: {
    loaders: [
     {
       test: /\.vue$/,
       loader: 'vue'
     },
    ]
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css"),
      // you can also include <style lang="less"> or other langauges
      less: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css!less")
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
  ]
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with a multiple entry points setup. `style.css` keeps being overwritten.